# Git hangs up during fetch or clone

Tags: git, https

I'm using git 1.8.4.2 on a VM (running up-to-date archlinux), let's call it machine A.
The remote origin is on a local network and works through https with authentification.
I can push to it without any problem, but fetch or clones usually hangs up.

I have another VM (running Ubuntu LTS 12.04) on the network (machine B), running git 1.7.9.5, that is able to fetch flawlessly.

I just so happen to be able to ssh from machine A to machine B, but not to the remote origin, so the current workaroung is to fetch from the remote origin to machine B in a temporary repository, then use git through ssh to fetch from B to A. But it is obviously not satisfying.

Here are some output using GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 (ip addresses and hostnames altered) :

== On machine A (failed attempt):

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git fetch
* Couldn't find host remote.localdomain in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1d60460
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1d60460) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to remote.localdomain port 443 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XX.XXX.XX...
* Connected to remote.localdomain (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=XX; ST=XXX; L=Xxxxxxx; O=Xxxxx; OU=Xxxxx; CN=remote.localdomain; name=remote; emailAddress=someone@somewhere.com
*    start date: 2013-01-10 14:30:42 GMT
*    expire date: 2023-01-08 14:30:42 GMT
*    issuer: C=XX; ST=XXX; L=Xxxxxxx; O=Xxxxx; OU=Xxxxx; CN=dev.localdomain; name=Pince; emailAddress=someone@somewhere.com
*    SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.8.4.2
Host: remote.localdomain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 09:21:45 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="LDAP Company.org"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Length: 290
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
* Connection #0 to host remote.localdomain left intact
* Couldn't find host remote.localdomain in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host remote.localdomain: 0x1d60e20
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host remote.localdomain
* Connected to remote.localdomain (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1d60460
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1d60460) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
> GET /repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.8.4.2
Host: remote.localdomain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 09:21:45 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="LDAP Company.org"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Length: 290
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host remote.localdomain left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://remote.localdomain/repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host remote.localdomain in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host remote.localdomain: 0x1d60e20
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host remote.localdomain
* Connected to remote.localdomain (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1d60460
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1d60460) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET /repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic VDAxMzY4NDU6cGFyaXM3MjI=
User-Agent: git/1.8.4.2
Host: remote.localdomain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 09:21:45 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
<
```

(it then stays stuck here)

== On machine B (successful attempt) :

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git fetch
* Couldn't find host remote.localdomain in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to remote.localdomain port 443 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XX.XXX.XX... * Connected to remote.localdomain (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* found 153 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*    server certificate verification SKIPPED
*    compression: NULL
*    cipher: AES-128-CBC
*    MAC: SHA1
> GET /repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.9.5
Host: remote.localdomain
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

* The requested URL returned error: 401
* Closing connection #0
* Couldn't find host remote.localdomain in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to remote.localdomain port 443 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XX.XXX.XX... * Connected to remote.localdomain (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* found 153 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* SSL re-using session ID
*    server certificate verification SKIPPED
*    compression: NULL
*    cipher: AES-128-CBC
*    MAC: SHA1
> GET /repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.9.5
Host: remote.localdomain
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 09:33:06 GMT
< Server: Apache
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="LDAP Company.org"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 401
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host remote.localdomain left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://remote.localdomain/repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host remote.localdomain in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host remote.localdomain
* Connected to remote.localdomain (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET /repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic VDAxMzY4NDU6cGFyaXM3MjI=
User-Agent: git/1.7.9.5
Host: remote.localdomain
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 09:33:06 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< 
* Connection #0 to host remote.localdomain left intact
```

(The command then simply returns with no error).

Anyone knows what the problem is ?

EDIT:
Further tests show that compiling v1.7.9.5 on machine A still doesn't work (exactly the same behaviour as v1.8.4.2).

So either this is Archlinux-specific, or this is caused by a different version of one of git's dependencies... I'd say curl and openssl are prime candidates.

After running the command several times, I once got a new error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://remote.localdomain/repository/': transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

I'm investigating this error...

Comment: Which operating systems and git implementations are you using? which commands are you issuing? is http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457 maybe related?

Comment: Edited the original post to answer (Archlinux & Ubuntu 12.04, standard git fetch). Each system use the git version from its package manager.